# DynamoDB getItem causing background SSLException

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am getting following exception in background for every getItem request to DynamoDb. It returns the response and the error happens while trying to close the socket connection. Any help is appreciated.

```
SSLException: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify at 
sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Alert, String, boolean, Throwable) at 
sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Alert, String, Throwable) at 
sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Alert, String) at 
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(boolean) at 
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput() at 
software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.internal.net.SdkSslSocket.shutdownInput() at 
org.apache.http.impl.BHttpConnectionBase.close() at 
org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection.close() at 
org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolEntry.closeConnection() at 
org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolEntry.close() at 
org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.getPoolEntryBlocking(Object, Object, long, TimeUnit, Future) at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.access$200(AbstractConnPool, Object, Object, long, TimeUnit, Future) at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool$2.get(long, TimeUnit) at 
org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool$2.get(long, TimeUnit) at 
org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.leaseConnection(Future, long, TimeUnit) at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$1.get(long, TimeUnit) at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2253.invoke(Object, Object[]) at 
jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Object, Object[]) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.internal.conn.ClientConnectionRequestFactory$Handler.invoke(Object, Method, Object[]) at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(HttpRoute, HttpRequestWrapper, HttpClientContext, HttpExecutionAware) at 
org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(HttpRoute, HttpRequestWrapper, HttpClientContext, HttpExecutionAware) at 
org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(HttpHost, HttpRequest, HttpContext) at 
org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(HttpUriRequest, HttpContext) at 
org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(HttpUriRequest, HttpContext) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.internal.impl.ApacheSdkHttpClient.execute(HttpUriRequest, HttpContext) at software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient.execute(HttpRequestBase) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient.access$500(ApacheHttpClient, HttpRequestBase) at software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient$1.call() at 
software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient$1.call() at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.util.MetricUtils.measureDurationUnsafe(Callable) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.MakeHttpRequestStage.executeHttpRequest(SdkHttpFullRequest, RequestExecutionContext) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.MakeHttpRequestStage.execute(SdkHttpFullRequest, RequestExecutionContext) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.MakeHttpRequestStage.execute(Object, RequestExecutionContext) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(Object, RequestExecutionContext) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(Object, RequestExecutionContext) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(Object, RequestExecutionContext) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(Object, RequestExecutionContext) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(SdkHttpFullRequest, RequestExecutionContext) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(Object, RequestExecutionContext) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(SdkHttpFullRequest, RequestExecutionContext) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(Object, RequestExecutionContext) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.execute(SdkHttpFullRequest, RequestExecutionContext) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.execute(Object, RequestExecutionContext) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(SdkHttpFullRequest, RequestExecutionContext) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(Object, RequestExecutionContext) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(Object, RequestExecutionContext) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(SdkHttpFullRequest, RequestExecutionContext) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(Object, RequestExecutionContext) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(SdkHttpFullRequest, RequestExecutionContext) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(SdkHttpFullRequest, RequestExecutionContext) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(Object, RequestExecutionContext) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(SdkHttpFullRequest, RequestExecutionContext) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(Object, RequestExecutionContext) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(Object, RequestExecutionContext) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(Object, RequestExecutionContext) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(SdkHttpFullRequest, RequestExecutionContext) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(Object, RequestExecutionContext) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonSyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(HttpResponseHandler) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.invoke(SdkHttpFullRequest, SdkRequest, ExecutionContext, HttpResponseHandler) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.doExecute(ClientExecutionParams, ExecutionContext, HttpResponseHandler) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.lambda$execute$1(ClientExecutionParams) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.measureApiCallSuccess(ClientExecutionParams, Supplier) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(ClientExecutionParams) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(ClientExecutionParams) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(ClientExecutionParams) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DefaultDynamoDbClient.getItem(GetItemRequest) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.internal.operations.CommonOperation.execute(TableSchema, OperationContext, DynamoDbEnhancedClientExtension, DynamoDbClient) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.internal.operations.TableOperation.executeOnPrimaryIndex(TableSchema, String, DynamoDbEnhancedClientExtension, DynamoDbClient) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.internal.client.DefaultDynamoDbTable.getItem(GetItemEnhancedRequest) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.internal.client.DefaultDynamoDbTable.getItem(Consumer) at 
software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.internal.client.DefaultDynamoDbTable.getItem(Key)
```

Using latest sdk 2.16.30 (software.amazon.awssdk:dynamodb-enhanced)

Server version: Apache Tomcat/9.0.41

Server built:  Dec 3 2020 11:43:00 UTC

Server number: 9.0.41.0

OS Name:    Linux

OS Version:   5.4.39-linuxkit

Architecture:  amd64

JVM Version:  11.0.9.1+1

JVM Vendor:   Oracle Corporation